# How to do one json request with same ID

Tags: json

I am trying to send one post request using JSON with the same ID.

```
{"name":"bob"}
{"name":"john"}
{"name":"doe"}
```

is it possible to send this post data using only one request instead of doing 3 different ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provided whatever you're sending it to understands what you're doing as well.

JSON has *arrays* as well as objects, so:

```
[
    {"name":"bob"},
    {"name":"john"},
    {"name":"doe"}
]
```

If you post that, you're sending a single array containing three objects to the other end.

Comment: I tried these two and did not work.. maybe server doesn't allow it? `[{"name":"bob"},{"name":"john"}]`
`{"name":["bob","john"]}`

Comment: @PaulWill: Right. As I said, the other end has to know what you're doing, too. You can't send three things to something that's expecting only one. If the other end isn't under your control, and they don't document a way of doing it, there's nothing you can do about it.